# Entity Framework won't save changes in database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework

When I try to add an item into the database, after running the app the data won't be in the database for long time memory. I don't know why, the connection is good and I already checked it many times.

```
 private void InsertIncomeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     float lf = (float)Convert.ToDouble(IncomeText.Text);
     MessageBox.Show(lf.ToString());

     DateTime date = (DateTime)MovDatePick.SelectedDate;
     Movments mv1 = new Movments();
     mv1.Sum = lf;
     mv1.Date = date.Date;

     db.TotalAll.FirstOrDefault().CurrentSum += lf;
     db.Movments.Add(mv1);
     db.SaveChanges();

     IncomeWin.Close();
     MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
     m.Show();
}
```

I am using VS 2017 Community and writing a WPF app.

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I'm **assuming** (from a lot of previous questions) that you have a SQL Server database, and your connection string *most likely* contains an `AttachDbFileName=.....` entry - correct?

If so: the whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.